# how to change language of retrieved content using language api in wikipedia?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I want two [api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Langlinks) call one for content and the other one for language change.

Answer (score 3):

Some experimentation shows that getting content links for one or more page titles, and specifying a required language for the content are part of the same API query. A specific language can be requested by providing a `lllang` parameter in the query string with a suitable [language code value](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Language#Language_code]).

For example to get the URL of a page with title "Albert Einstein" translated into Egyptian Arabic (code "arz") in the API's sandbox:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=langlinks&titles=Albert+Einstein&llprop=url&lllang=arz
```

Depending on the application and query volumes, it can improve efficiency to request data for multiple titles and/or all languages in one call and search through the results, as opposed to making many separate, individual calls.

FWIW. The API documentation seems to lack instructions to provide specific parameters for a "langlinks` or other query types simply by adding them as key-value pairs to the query string.